# Find the sum of values of $x$ that satisfies $\left | 3x-3 \right | + \left | 4x-4 \right | + \left | 5x-5 \right | \geq 24$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Find the sum of values of $x$ that satisfies $\left | 3x-3 \right | + \left  | 4x-4 \right | + \left | 5x-5 \right | \geq 24$

What I did so far:

$$\left | x-1 \right | \times \left | 3+4+5 \right | \geq 24$$

$$\left | x-1 \right | \times \left | 12 \right | \geq 24$$

And that is pretty much that because I never dealt with absolute values in multiplications before.

Comment: There are infinitely many such values, even if you are only looking for integers $x$.

Comment: The question would make more sense with $\leq 24$ and $x$ an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your linear term are factorable, they contain $|x-1|$, so we have $$3|x-1|+4|x-1|+5|x-1|\geq24$$ which results in $|x-1|\geq2$. 
it should be obvious that there are infinitely many $x$ values that work here.
Not sure where the problem came from, but on a side note, had the inequality been "less or equal to 24" and $x$ been an integer, the problem would have made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Factorise, $|x-1|$, so we have 
$$3|x-1|+4|x-1|+5|x-1|\geq24$$

Let $$|x-1|=t$$

So we have $$3t+4t+5t\geq24$$

or $$12t\geq24$$

or $$t\geq2$$

So $$|x-1|\geq2$$

There are two cases. If you want to know how to solve this comment here. The solution is:

$$x\leq-1$$
$$x\geq3$$

Still confused? Follow this: [Step-by-Step Solution](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/absolute-inequalities-calculator/%5Cleft%7Cx-1%5Cright%7C%5Cge%202)

The sum would (theoretically) be = -3